# Receive an email from someone to localhost using PHP

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, mail-server

I have a question about receiving emails.

Using Ubuntu as the server, I have setup simple mail sending capabilities using the following command line:

```
sudo tasksel mail-server
```

This allows me to send emails using the command line:

```
echo 'body' | sendmail recipient@example.net
```

or the following in PHP:

```
mail($to, $subj, $msg)
```

Then `recipient@example.net` receives the email no problem.

The email comes from `oshirowanen@desktop`

If `recipient@example.net` sends an email back to `oshirowanen@desktop`, how do I receive it on the `localhost` from the command prompt or php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, localhost is local so you'll need a fixed IP and a nameserver for your computer and propagate that domain to your computer so it can receive emails over the internet.

Answer (score 0):

oshirowanen@desktop is not a fully formed email address, and cannot be replied to by anyone from the internet. In order to receive email to a domain, you generally need to register a domain, then you can set it up to use your ubuntu server as a mail exchanger or smtp client if you wish.